# Why are these JavaScript functions undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to understand the output of [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jarron/meb6Lcas/).

I'm loading jQuery UI via [Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/), using the "External Resources" option on the left.

Some things are puzzling me...

- jQuery UI *partially* works. I can drag the "drag me" div around.

  So jQuery UI `.draggable()` ([docs](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)) is good.

  On the other hand `.button()` ([docs](https://jqueryui.com/button/)) doesn't apply the jQuery UI theme CSS.

  Why would `.draggable()` work, but not `.button()`? (Syntax error?)
- How can `draggable` be `undefined`?

  It works, so it must be a function, right?
- How can `click` be `undefined`?

  `click()` is from jQuery, and `$` is a function. Wouldn't `click` be one too?

Here's the JS...

```
(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.dr').draggable();

    $('.btn').button();

    $('.btn').click(function(event) {
      alert('Clicked');
    });

    $('.output').append('typeof $: ' + typeof $ + '<br />');

    $('.output').append('typeof draggable: ' + typeof draggable + '<br />');

    $('.output').append('typeof click: ' + typeof click + '<br />');

    $('.output').append('typeof button: ' + typeof button + '<br />');

  });

}());
```

The output I'm getting is...

```
typeof $: function  // As expected.
typeof draggable: undefined  // How can it be undefined and still work?
typeof click: undefined  // ???
typeof button: undefined
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that `$(`…`).draggable` can be referenced as `draggable`? That’s not how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions used above are `$().draggable`, `$().click` and `$().button`, not `draggable`, `click` and `button`, which, at that scope, end up looking for  `window.draggable`, `window.click` and `window.button`.

Another way of getting the type of `$().draggable`, `$().click` and `$().button` is through `$.prototype`, which is commonly aliased as `$.fn`. So:

`$().draggable`, `$().click` and `$().button`, or
`$.prototype.draggable`, `$.prototype.click` and `$.prototype.button` or 
`$.fn.draggable`, `$.fn.click` and `$.fn.button` are the same. And those are different from `draggable`, `click` and `button` which, in that function of yours, is the same as `window.draggable`, `window.click` and `window.button`.

Comment: Alright, I see what you're saying. Thanks for the help. I tested `typeof $().draggable` and indeed it's a function. Ok, great. That's one thing cleared up. Any thoughts on why `.button()` isn't applying the jQuery UI CSS?

Comment: Seems like a bug in jsfiddle. It did not add correctly the CSS "External resource" where you typed the .css file. I just removed it and retyped and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/meb6Lcas/4/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you aren't tying those to anything, so it ends up looking at `window`.

You should be looking off of `$.fn`.

Answer (score -1):

Functions are different than methods. `draggable` is not equal to `$('.dr').draggable`, and so on.